# Input for read_csv pandas function

Tags: python, pandas, subprocess

I need to feed to pandas read_csv the output of one command I execute with Popen.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
pandas.read_csv(stdout,index_col=0)
```

But obviously stdout is a string and it's interpreted as a path. In the API documentation it says that "any object with a read() method (such as a file handle or StringIO)" can be an input to the read_csv function. How can I get such an object out of the Popen commmand? The final objective is to not write to disk.

Also when I write to disk the contents of stdout I can see that the csv has double quotes for each line

```
alvarobrandon$ head csvfile.csv
"1507109453,<,java,12447,a3e9c495869d,docker,9.0.4.130,9.0.2.131,9.0.2.131,9.0.4.130,56182,9092,9092,56182,tcp"
"1507109453,<,java,1244,a3e9c495869d,docker,9.0.4.130,9.0.2.131,9.0.2.131,9.0.4.130,56182,9092,9092,56182,tcp"
"1507109453,<,java,12447,a3e9c495869d,docker,9.0.4.130,9.0.2.131,9.0.2.131,9.0.4.130,56182,9092,9092,56182,tcp"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is to read from stdout and store that data into a file-like `StringIO` object. Here is a minimal working example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import io
import subprocess
import pandas

cmd = ('cat', '/tmp/csvfile')
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
csv = io.StringIO(process.stdout.read().decode())
data = pandas.read_csv(csv, index_col=0)
csv.close()
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT (output isn't really CSV, so we have to sanitize it a bit before parsing):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import io
import subprocess
import pandas

cmd = ('cat', '/tmp/csvfile')
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
csv = io.StringIO()
for line in process.stdout:
    csv.write(line.decode().strip('"\n') + '\n')
csv.seek(0)
data = pandas.read_csv(csv, index_col=0)
csv.close()
```

Comment: to convert from bytes to text

Comment: it seems like it's doing something with the \n newline characters because I get a 1847941 rows x 0 columns pandas dataframe, with all the information as an index

Comment: that rather seems like a separator problem to me; have a look at the `sep` parameter for `read_csv`

Comment: I checked that as well with sep=',' but no luck. One hint I think is that when  dump the output a csv it appears with double quotes. I will update the question to reflect this

Comment: ah, I see. this output is not CSV. if you don't control the command generating this output, you have to take care of it in Python. I'll update the answer accordingly.